# why view for header in section does not appear properly when the tableview style is grouped in iOS, objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm working with a tableview which has four sections. for each section I have implemented a header view. when I use the `tableview` `style` as `Plain` it works properly. but if I use the `tableview` `style` as `Grouped` it looks wired.

this is how I implement the `tableview` delegate methods.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 4;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(section == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (section == 2)
    {
        return 3;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width, 50)];
    UILabel *titlelabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 0, screenSize.width-80, 50)];

    if (section == 0)
    {
        titlelabel.text = @"Flight Summary";
        [headerView addSubview:titlelabel];
        return headerView;
    }
    else if(section == 1)
    {
        titlelabel.text = @"Price Summary";
        [headerView addSubview:titlelabel];
        return headerView;
    }
    else if (section == 2)
    {
        titlelabel.text = @"Traveller Details";
        [headerView addSubview:titlelabel];
        return headerView;
    }
    else
    {
        titlelabel.text = @"Book Now";
        [headerView addSubview:titlelabel];
        return headerView;
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"checkcell"];
    return cell;
}
```

this is the screenshot when I use tableview style as `Plain`

[image]

link to image  : [image with plain style](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z5dw0harlhlvf4t/Screen%20Shot%202016-08-18%20at%2010.55.01.png?dl=0)

this is the screenshot when I use tableview style as `Grouped`

[image]

link to the image : [image with grouped stye](https://www.dropbox.com/s/flh86yy027qffdy/Screen%20Shot%202016-08-18%20at%2010.53.38.png?dl=0)

I have no idea what is going on, hope your help with this.

Comment: why is this happen only for `Grouped` tableview style

Comment: Did you implement the `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` method?

Comment: no I didn't implement, because most of the time I used `Plain` style and didn't require that method. @rmaddy

Comment: Read the docs for `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`. It clearly states that you must implement `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`. It doesn't matter whether it is a plain or grouped table.

Comment: k got it and thank @rmaddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It requires to set the section header height. Try the below way, Hope this helps you.

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 50
}
```